# NHibernate Nested Projection

Tags: nhibernate, queryover, nhibernate-projections

Not sure this is even possible but I'll explain anyway.

I have a custom projection for doing simple arithmetic in a query which works perfectly in a single projection.

```
namespace Custom.Projections
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using global::NHibernate;
    using global::NHibernate.Criterion;
    using global::NHibernate.SqlCommand;
    using global::NHibernate.Type;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a CalculatedProjection
    /// </summary>
    public class CalculatedProjection : SimpleProjection
    {
        private readonly CalculationType calculationType;
        private readonly IProjection firstProjection;
        private readonly IProjection secondProjection;
        private readonly string firstPropertyName;
        private readonly string secondPropertyName;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the CalculatedProjection class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">The type of calculation</param>
        /// <param name="firstPropertyName">The name of the first property</param>
        /// <param name="secondPropertyName">The name of the second property</param>
        protected internal CalculatedProjection(CalculationType type, string firstPropertyName, string secondPropertyName)
        {
            this.calculationType = type;
            this.firstPropertyName = firstPropertyName;
            this.secondPropertyName = secondPropertyName;
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the CalculatedProjection class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">The type of calculation</param>
        /// <param name="firstProjection">The first projection</param>
        /// <param name="secondProjection">The second projection</param>
        protected internal CalculatedProjection(CalculationType type, IProjection firstProjection, IProjection secondProjection)
        {
            this.calculationType = type;
            this.firstProjection = firstProjection;
            this.secondProjection = secondProjection;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The type of calculation
        /// </summary>
        public enum CalculationType
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Addition + 
            /// </summary>
            Addition,

            /// <summary>
            /// Subtraction -
            /// </summary>
            Subtraction,

            /// <summary>
            /// Division /
            /// </summary>
            Division,

            /// <summary>
            /// Division *
            /// </summary>
            Multiplication,
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether the projection is grouped
        /// </summary>
        public override bool IsGrouped
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether IsAggregate.
        /// </summary>
        public override bool IsAggregate
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the calculation into a string
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The string representation of the calculation</returns>
        public override string ToString()
        {
            var firstValue = this.firstProjection != null ? this.firstProjection.ToString() : this.firstPropertyName;
            var secondValue = this.secondProjection != null ? this.secondProjection.ToString() : this.secondPropertyName;

            return "(" + firstValue + TypeToString(this.calculationType) + secondValue + ")";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the types involved in the query
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="criteria">The current criteria</param>
        /// <param name="criteriaQuery">The criteria query</param>
        /// <returns>An array of IType</returns>
        public override IType[] GetTypes(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
        {
            var types = new List<IType>();

            if (this.firstProjection != null)
            {
                types.AddRange(this.firstProjection.GetTypes(criteria, criteriaQuery));
            }
            else
            {
                types.Add(criteriaQuery.GetType(criteria, this.firstPropertyName));
            }

            if (this.secondProjection != null)
            {
                types.AddRange(this.secondProjection.GetTypes(criteria, criteriaQuery));
            }
            else
            {
                types.Add(criteriaQuery.GetType(criteria, this.secondPropertyName));
            }

            return types.ToArray();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the objects to an sql string representation
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="criteria">The criteria being used in the query</param>
        /// <param name="loc">The location in the query</param>
        /// <param name="criteriaQuery">The criteria query</param>
        /// <param name="enabledFilters">List of enabled filters</param>
        /// <returns>The calculation as an sql string</returns>
        public override SqlString ToSqlString(ICriteria criteria, int loc, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery, IDictionary<string, IFilter> enabledFilters)
        {
            string first, second;

            if ((this.firstProjection != null) && (this.secondProjection != null))
            {
                first = global::NHibernate.Util.StringHelper.RemoveAsAliasesFromSql(this.firstProjection.ToSqlString(criteria, loc, criteriaQuery, enabledFilters)).ToString();
                second = global::NHibernate.Util.StringHelper.RemoveAsAliasesFromSql(this.secondProjection.ToSqlString(criteria, loc, criteriaQuery, enabledFilters)).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                first = criteriaQuery.GetColumn(criteria, this.firstPropertyName);
                second = criteriaQuery.GetColumn(criteria, this.secondPropertyName);
            }

            return new SqlString(new object[] { "(", first, TypeToString(this.calculationType), second, ") as y", loc.ToString(), "_" });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts the objects to an sql string representation
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="criteria">The criteria being used in the query</param>
        /// <param name="criteriaQuery">The criteria query</param>
        /// <param name="enabledFilters">List of enabled filters</param>
        /// <returns>The calculation as an sql string</returns>
        public override SqlString ToGroupSqlString(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery, IDictionary<string, IFilter> enabledFilters)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            return new SqlString(new object[] { sb.ToString() });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the string symbol of calculation type
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">The type to use</param>
        /// <returns>The string representation</returns>
        private static string TypeToString(CalculationType type)
        {
            switch (type)
            {
                case CalculationType.Addition: return "+";
                case CalculationType.Subtraction: return "-";
                case CalculationType.Multiplication: return "*";
                case CalculationType.Division: return "/";
                default: return "+";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am now trying to use this projection from within another using the QueryOver syntax as below:

```
public override IList<DaySummaryDetail> Execute()
{
    // ReSharper disable PossibleNullReferenceException
    var calculated = Custom.Projections.Calculated(CalculatedProjection.CalculationType.Subtraction, "Duration.EndTime", "Duration.StartTime");

    DaySummaryDetail detail = null;

    return Session.QueryOver<WorkingDay>()
        .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(Projections.Group<WorkingDay>(x => x.Date).WithAlias(() => detail.Date))
        .Select(Projections.Sum(calculated)).WithAlias(() => detail.TotalMinutes))
        .Where(x => x.Person.Id == 1)
        .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<DaySummaryDetail>())
        .List<DaySummaryDetail>();

    // ReSharper restore PossibleNullReferenceException
}
```

The query generated is correct:

```
SELECT
    this_.DATE_TIME as y0_,
    sum((this_.END_MINS-this_.START_MINS)) as y1_ 
FROM
    WORKINGDAY this_ 
WHERE
    this_.PERSON_ID = @p0 
GROUP BY
    this_.DATE_TIME;
@p0 = 1 [Type: Int64 (0)]
```

The issue I have is that I get the following exception:

NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException : could not execute query
[ SELECT this_.DATE_TIME as y0_, sum((this_.END_MINS-this_.START_MINS)) as y1_ FROM WORKINGDAY this_ WHERE this_.PERSON_ID = @p0 GROUP BY this_.DATE_TIME ]
  Name:cp0 - Value:8977
[SQL: SELECT this_.DATE_TIME as y0_, sum((this_.END_MINS-this_.START_MINS)) as y1_ FROM WORKINGDAY this_ WHERE this_.PERSON_ID = @p0 GROUP BY this_.DATE_TIME]
  ----> System.IndexOutOfRangeException : y2_

StackTrace:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, String name)
at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaLoader.GetResultColumnOrRow(Object[] row, IResultTransformer customResultTransformer, IDataReader rs, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters) 
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaLoader.List(ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(CriteriaImpl criteria, IList results)
at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List(IList results)
at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List()
```

As you can see from the the query the aliasing is using two values (y0_ and y1_) yet somehow it is looking for y2_.
I assume this is because I am using a nested projection here which it can not deal with OR is it that I have implemented or called the projection incorrectly?

Any help or alternate suggestions would be great. I realise this can be done in a number of ways using HQL etc. but was particularly interested in using QueryOver

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

School boy error.

The GetTypes method on of the projection should return the types involved in the result of the projection. I was returning the types of the fields involved.

Should look like this:

```
public override IType[] GetTypes(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
{
    return new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.Int32 };
}
```

Hope this saves someone some time